# Eliminate duplicate rows using MySQL DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a world db. The table below was generated with:

```
SELECT *
FROM geolocations
WHERE city = 'Santa Cruz'
```

The table contains multiple entries for each city, it once contained a Zip Code field.
I want to delete duplicate entries for cities. I tried using:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp
SELECT DISTINCT city, region
FROM geolocations
```

The previous statement eliminates the duplicate entries, but how do I get id and other fields to copy to new table?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
id    Country   Region     City       Latitutde         Longitude
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
4683    US  CA  Santa Cruz  37.0447998047   -122.1020965576      
5748    US  CA  Santa Cruz  36.9712982178   -121.9875030518      
9506    US  CA  Santa Cruz  37.0101013184   -122.0324020386      
11205   US  CA  Santa Cruz  37.0344009399   -121.9796981812      
11379   US  CA  Santa Cruz  36.9898986816   -122.0603027344      
13146   US  CA  Santa Cruz  37.0101013184   -122.0324020386      
14362   US  CA  Santa Cruz  37.0101013184   -122.0324020386      
30055   BO  03  Santa Cruz  -12.2833003998  -66.2500000000   
31760   ES  59  Santa Cruz  42.6666984558   -2.3499999046    
39477   AR  22  Santa Cruz  -27.6667003632  -64.2667007446   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You're not really eliminating duplicate rows, ya know.  As you can see from the sample data you provided, those aren't duplicate rows.  Some of the fields in the row are duplicate, but apparently some of the location data varies for each row.  SQL can't magically pick a random instance of that extra data for you.

I think you should break up this table into two tables:  One that holds Country, Region, and City.  Then another that has relates back to that table, and that holds the latitude and longitude readings.  The second table would potentially have multiple rows per row in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

IN MSSQL it's this"

```
SELECT distinct City, Region
INTO tmp
FROM geolocations 
WHERE City = 'Santa Cruz'
```

In MYSQL, you can use [select into table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Although I havent tested it, something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO tmp(City, Region)
    SELECT distinct City, Region
    FROM geolocations WHERE WHERE City = 'Santa Cruz'
```

Comment: I am getting _ error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1_  when I execute `INSERT INTO tmp (location_id, country, region, city, latitude, longitude) SELECT DISTINCT region, city FROM geolocations ` I want to SELECT only city, and region distinctly and transfer over the other fields for the now single entry.

Comment: Ahar.... the but other fields aren't unique, in your data for each city there are multiple Latitudes and latitudes, by adding the other fields you are making the query non unique.  You will need to approach it in a number of steps.  Create the unique records first, and then in another query set the average long/latt fot each record ( or manually set the correct long/latt)

Comment: There are 300K entries in the DB it don't think manually updating is a viable option and also there is no need to average I only need a single point close to the city.

Comment: ok, so it is 4 steps.  Step one is to get the unique cities and regions into a separate table with new IDs, with the geocodes and country codes being blank/null.  Step two is to look up the average Geocodes for each country (you would probably want to trim out the weird geocodes at the same time), and update them in your new table.  Step 3 is to look up the most common country code for each city and update that in your new table.  Step 4 is to use the new table to update any foreign keys with the new ID in the new table, you will also need to change any relationships at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As Marvo said those are not duplicate rows perse but some fields duplicated. The best approach could be to redesign your database and break that table into two -at least-. This could serve you as a starting point:

First create a table that contains different-uniques- cities:

```
CREATE TABLE city SELECT DISTINCT city FROM db
```

Add a primary key to that table:

```
ALTER TABLE city ADD id_city INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST
```

Create a table that contains all your records and the id of the corresponding city that each record belongs to:

```
CREATE TABLE records SELECT db.id,db.country, db.region, city.id_city, db.lat,db.long FROM db INNER JOIN city ON db.city = city.city
```

You can make another one for cities asocciated with countries if you wish.

Comment: The first 2 steps went smoothly, but When I execute this `CREATE TABLE records SELECT db.id,db.country, db.region, city.id_city, db.lat,db.long FROM db INNER JOIN city ON db.city = city.city` it times out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This query worked I wanted to select distinct city, region combinations and group it with its associated data in the new table.

```
CREATE TABLE clean_gls SELECT * FROM geolocations GROUP BY city, region;
```